# Why does my phone intermittently add Title and Subject attributes?

Tags: metadata, digital, mobile

I have taken a lot of photos, over the past couple of days, using the default 'Camera' App that came with my Huawei Mobile phone.  I have since uploaded these Photos to my Computer, via Google Photos.

I have noticed that a small minority of these Photographs have had random letters inserted into their 'Title' and 'Subject' attributes.  These are viewable when I right click on the Photographs and head to Properties > Details:

[image]

The only pattern I have noticed is that these random letters only appear image files, where the photo was taken with the front facing camera.  Even then, the `fbt' appearance is still intermittent.

I have also looked for patterns in the below but could find nothing:

- Are attributes added for Landscape/Portrait images?
- Does a specific Day/Time affect whether attributes are added or not?
- Are attributes assigned, based on whether I am using WiFi or Mobile Data?
- Is there a link with File sizes?
- Could Google Photos be adding these entries?

It appears to be random.  Has anyone else experienced this and/or have any idea what is causing this to occur?

**Phone Details:**

- Make and Model:  Huawei Honor 10 Lite
- Model:  HRY-LX1
- Android Version:  10
- EMUI: 10.0.0

Comment: I feel this is not really photography related, but is more about mobile (photo) app configuration. However I'm curious to see what this might be so I won't vote to close (for now). 
About the random characters: Is it always a three letter combination (like `fbt`) or is it sometimes an (English) word?

Comment: Have you try to transfer photos via cable, directly from phone storage and check if something change?

Comment: Is it by any chance a Huawei phone? If you [search Flickr for fbt](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=fbt) you'll find many pictures with "fbt" as the title or description. When EXIF data is available it often lists a Huawei phone as a device.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke:  The majority of the entries are `fbt` but there have been other 3 letter combinations, in the past.  The entries have never been an English word nor have they been anything other than 3 random letters.

Comment: @RomeoNinov:  I have not actually tried the Cable approach.  I shall, as soon as I am able to and update accordingly. :-)

Comment: Any relation between these and the use of the front or back cameras?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke:  Using a Data Transfer cable does not seem to affect anything.  I think @xenoid could be on to something though, as the inclusion of this `fbt` entry only seems to appear across image files, where the photo was taken with the front facing camera.  I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Then I think that's your answer: the Huawei adds the title/description to photos taken with the front facing camera. The Flickr photos I linked to earlier seem to support that. Feel free to create an answer and accept your own answer.
*Why* the Huawei phone does this cannot be answered, unless you contact Huawei and ask (and even then I doubt you'll have an answer).

Comment: @Craig Please add output of `exiftool -a -G` for one of the affected photos.  You can get ExifTool from [exiftool.org](https://exiftool.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Huawei never did respond to my query relating to this question.  As such, I am non the wiser as to why `fbt` is sometimes automatically populated to some of the photos taken in selfie-mode.  Online searches bring up suggestions that this `fbt` refers to some optical related piece of hardware as well as the Metadata entry being a glitch in Huawei's software.

What I can tell you, however, is that I have since figured that such Metadata entries only appear in photos that have been taken with the 'Portrait' mode switched on.

I am unsure why, other than a possible software glitch, but at least the reason is now known; should anyone need to know. :-)